# perl script for replace data

Tags: perl, date, replace

I have the script below. Input data is date. What I need to do is to filter out the date which is no more than one week old and replace it with '0' and two weeks old replacing it with '1'. The other dates should be deleted (I haven't get it there). Here's the script but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    use Date::Parse;
    use Date::Format;
    use Date::Manip;

    sub f {

    my $x = shift;
    my $env = shift;

    my $time = str2time($x);
    my $oneweekold = str2time(time2str('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', (time()-60*60*24*7)));
    my $twoweeksold = str2time(time2str('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', (time()-60*60*24*14)));

    return '0' if $time < $oneweekold;
    return '1' if $time < $twoweeksold;

    return $x;

    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add sample inputs

Comment: Note that any answer with 24*60*60 in it is wrong since not all days have 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for a sub that returns three values, where one of the values indicates a need for filtering, and two of those value are actual values. This is a mess.

Instead, let's write a sub that return the number of weeks ago. You can filter on that, and format for output based on that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Date::Parse qw( str2time );
use DateTime    qw( );

# ...    
# -2 = 7..13 days from now.
# -1 = 0.. 6 days from now.
#  0 = 1.. 7 days ago.
#  1 = 8..14 days ago.
# ...
sub weeks_ago {
   my ($ref, $dt) = @_;
   if ($dt >= $ref) {
      return -int( ( $ref->delta_days($dt)->in_units('days') + 7 ) / 7 );
   } else {
      return int( ( $ref->delta_days($dt)->in_units('days') - 1 ) / 7 );
   }
}

my $ref = DateTime->today( time_zone => 'local' );

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => str2time('2013:03:27T08:08:17.1823213') );
my $weeks_ago = weeks_ago($ref, $dt);
if (0 <= $weeks_ago && $weeks_ago <= 1) {   # Filtering
   say $weeks_ago;                          # Formatting (Actually, none needed)
}
```